Is it possible to configure apaches kafka topic operator to watch all namespaces in cluster?
I have a deployment of the strimzi operator that manages kafka operators, however whenever a developer adds a new kafkaTopic claim, the operator do not pick it up because it will only listen to the kafka namespace. I would like it to listen to all namespaces.
